# position fixed to absolute on scroll make my img jump

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-position, positioning

I'd like to see a background image (not full screen), previously positioned as "fixed", slowly move toward the top part of the web page and then disappear like happens with absolute positioning, but only after a certain number of pixels.
I used the "addClass" event to change the positioning from fixed to absolute.

Reached the wanted amount of pixels, the image is affected by the new class but instead of starting a smooth movement upwards, it jumps in the position in which it would be if it has always defined by an absolute position. Instead, I like it to start the movement from the position where it is.

This is the Jquery code (the class ".scrolled" just says "position:absolute")

```
   <script>
       $(document).on("scroll", function () {
var pixels = $(document).scrollTop()
if (pixels > 350) { 
$("img").addClass("scrolled")
} else {
$("img").removeClass("scrolled")
}
})
    </script>
```

---

UPDATE
In the following, I'll add my HTML and CSS code. I'm sorry guys, I'm a beginner and I didn't wonder that would be fundamental having them to answer my question.

HTML

```
<div class="grid"> <div class="row"><div class="col-6"><img src="https://www.illibraio.it/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/francesco-carofiglio-1.jpg" alt="FotoPortfolio"></div></div>


        <div class="row">
     <p class="page">
      Hi everybody!<br>
      My name is Francesco Cagnola<br> and I'm a communication designer.<br>
   Recently, I've graduated at Politecnico di Milano with a degree in Communication Design.
      I'm experienced in videomaking and photography but I can do beautiful graphics too.
        I'm based in Milan but I'm spending a period in London to breath this vibrant city!
         <br><br>
         "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
    </p> 
    </div> </div>
```

CSS

```
.grid {
   width: 100%;
}

.row {
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.col-6 {
    width: 50%;
}

body {
  background-color: #000000;
  color:black;
 margin: 0px
}
img {    position: fixed;
    top:15%;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 50%;
    right:5%;
    z-index: 0;
}
.scrolled{
  position:absolute;
}

.page {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
 padding: 14px 16px;
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: you might want to post your css

Comment: kindly post your html and css

Comment: Hello guys, thank you for answering.
I'm sorry to not having added HTML and CSS before: I'm just a beginner and I didn't wonder that they would be necessary for asking help.  If you still wanted to help me would be great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are removing class scrolled, you can add another class called for example 'animation'.

And 'animation' will have this in CSS:

```
.animation {
    position: absolute;
    animation-name: godown;
    animation-duration: ...s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes godown {
    0% {
        top: 350px;
    }
    100% {
        top: 0px;
    }
```

And this will be jQuery:

```
if (pixels > 350) { 
    $("img").addClass("scrolled");
    $("img").removeClass("animation");
} else {
    $("img").removeClass("scrolled");
    $("img").addClass("animation");
}
```

But scrolled has to have this in CSS:

```
.scrolled {
    position: absolute;
}
```

I'm on my mobile now so my testing is limited, but it should actually work.

UPDATE:
This is CSS:

```
.grid {
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.col-6 {
  width: 50%;
}

body {
  background-color: #000000;
  color:black;
 margin: 0px
}
img {    
  position: fixed;
  top:15%;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 50%;
  right:5%;
  z-index: 0;
}
.scrolled{
  position:absolute;
  animation-name: godown;
  animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.page {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
}

@keyframes godown {
0% {
    top: 350px;
}
100% {
    top: 0px;
}
```

And this is JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $(document).on("scroll", function () {
  var pixels = $(document).scrollTop()
  if (pixels > 350) {
    $("img").addClass("scrolled");
  } else {
    $("img").removeClass("scrolled");
    }
  });
});
```

And it works fine, when you scroll 350px from top, img goes smoothly to position absolute.

2nd update:

You can "simulate" `position: fixed` in jQuery. Just like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
var pixels = $(document).scrollTop()
  if (pixels < 350) {
    $('img').css(
      'top', $(this).scrollTop() + "px"); 
  }  else {
        $('img').css(
          'top' : '0px',
          'transition' : '.5s');
      }
});
```

And CSS:

```
img {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Hello SenTisso, thank you very much for answering me.
I've tried to add the code you suggested me but I think that adding the part related to the keyframes seem to conflict. After I add this specific part the page displays only the img not in its position, the text disappears! 

I've updated my question maybe it could be helpful in helping me :)
Thanks again

Comment: If i understand it right, you are basically moving ONLY that image ?? Or something with it ??

Comment: In the beginning, the image is fixed as the background of the first paragraph. So the text flows over it. Once the paragraph that refers to the img finishes, I'd like that the image would slide out from the top with it

Comment: Hi SenTisso! Sorry I haven't received the notification for the update!
Thank you a lot! It works! :D

Comment: So it does what you wanted ?? Nice :D btw. if it works, can you mark my answer as solution ?? Thanks :)

Comment: Honestly, I'd like the animation to go jointly with the scroll but I'll try to figure out by myself. You gave me a great start :)

Comment: yeah! Top! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Then put a position relative on the CSS for images without top, left, right, bottom and it'll be alright.
Don't really know if you don't put your HTML and CSS

Comment: Hi Kevin, thank you for answering. 
I've just added my HTML and CSS. 
If you still wanted to help me would be great :)